# Spinner clear edittext and buttons

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

By changing the spinner, two buttons that have on screen are erased your text. I have no idea what it is. In other activity, the same happens in edittexts, the values comes from an database. Everything except this error is ok.

Below i put parts of code that relates with spinner and buttons.

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_cad__parametros"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="diariodebordo.sph.com.sphdiariodebordo.Cad_Parametros">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_embarcacoes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_salvar"
                android:text="salvar"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_voltar"
                android:text="voltar"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:onClick="voltar"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

in Activity:

```
    package diariodebordo.sph.com.sphdiariodebordo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Cad_Parametros extends MainActivity{
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cad_parametros);
        loadSpinnerEmbarcacao();
        //se onclick button redirect to method salvar()
        Button botaoSalvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_salvar);
        botaoSalvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                salvar();
            }
        });
    }
    //save the params
    public void salvar() {}
    //load rows of spinner
    private void loadSpinnerEmbarcacao() {
        List<String> equip = new ArrayList<String>();
        Spinner spinner_embarcacao = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_embarcacoes);
        equip.add(0, "first row");
        equip.add(1, "second row");
        equip.add(2, "third row");
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, equip);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner_embarcacao.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
    //back
    public void voltar(View v){ finish(); }
}
```

where is my mistake? :\

Thanks!

Comment: Already I apologize for my poor English and helped by the google translate!

Comment: No part of this code should be modifying the text of an buttons other than the spinner. Where's the issue?

Comment: that's the problem, nowhere do I change the button text.

Comment: question updated, I put the whole activity!

Comment: came from MainActivity, before put the whole code I changed the extends to see if is the error. But nothing!

Comment: the method voltar is this:
 
public void voltar(View v){ finish(); }

Comment: I put the method, but error in spinner continues. The initialize and load seems ok?

Comment: Yep, still exist! :(

Comment: Could you please show a [mcve], then with an [edit]? I could try to reproduce the problem in my device

Comment: Question updated! It's ok?

Comment: Yeah, I'll check it out.